# Error with no line number and class: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When I am publishing my ASP.NET website, VS 2010 shows an error:

> Error  1   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

There is not neither a class name nor a line number.

What could cause this error?

Another point, the web site works with no error when debugging.

Comment: Did you try restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: OMG! Is that so easy?

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: It is,
Step 1: Restart problematic application.
Step 2: Restart computer
Step 3: ???
Step 4: Profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting Visual Studio, the error message has gone. Thanks to [C Baurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82333/c-bauer)

Comment: When an error occurred it is not simple to carefree by restarting because it might happen again, Check your Event Viewer.